# How to use Webrtc api for video chat

Tags: webrtc

I need to use Webrtc api for video and audio call between two users.Actually i have a Elearning learning management system with  many users recently i have developed a chat system so that users logged in LMS can chat each other using simple php,ajax and jquery.Now i  have implemented only text chat.

I need to develop video chat also like Google hangout and facebook video chat.Users registered in my system are having different email domains means some one have gmail account ,yahoo account etc.

Expecting quick reply

Thanks

Comment: So, the plethora of tutorials out there did not help at all? I find that hard to believe....

Comment: Actually i am very new to Webrtc .I need to know how can we hangout like video chat in that we are not sharing any link between users just showing a pop up window in the Screen and used to chat?.....i need to use webrtc like that..Please mention any tutorials or links that may help me..Thanks in advance

Comment: what do you mean no link between users? This is for video chat? [This one](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/basics/) and [This one](https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/docs/WebRTC-PeerConnection.html) are both good tutorials

Comment: Thanks you very much for the quick response . When an user logs  in my system he/she can see online users .Clicking each user will generate a chat window where he/she can chat with the particular user.In the chat window i have a video icon clicking the video icon must generate a video pop up window in both users side so that video chat can be done....As far as i  know webrtc will generate a link and both user will share it and video chat through browser...I need to do automatic sharing ,pop up etc just like facebook....I think you understand the problem.

Comment: You will need a signalling server. Once you have done some work and run into a technical issue then ask another question pertaining to it.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the information.Actually i have set up a video chat environment locally using http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/basics/ ...obtained the local devices using getUserMedia().I am not able to create a signalling server locally inorder to create a peer to peer connection and coordinating communication.Please mention any useful links for the same.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

To get started with WebRTC, I would suggest to first have a look at the [following tutorial on WebRTC fundamentals](http://pluralsight.com/training/Courses/TableOfContents/webrtc-fundamentals).

You can then start to implement [the native WebRTC API](http://www.webrtc.org/reference/native-apis) but be aware that you won’t be able to establish a video call if you don’t add a signaling server which does not come built-in with the WebRTC API.

Also if the caller and callee are connected to two different networks, you’ll often need ICE, STUN and TURN servers. Video chat is more complex to implement than text chat and if you don’t have the time and the resources to learn the fundamentals and deploy servers, I would suggest you give a try to a WebRTC Platform that already have an up and running cloud infrastructure to which you can access through an API.

It is the type of [WebRTC Platform](http://www.weemo.com/webrtc-platform/) that we offer at Weemo.